# Angular $timeout only with last change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to use only one instance of Angulars $timeout?

For example, there is this code:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    $timeout(function() {
        console.log('test');
    }, 2000);
}
```

Evaluating this code, angular will return 10 console messages after 2 seconds. Is there a way to get only one last message?

EDIT: Loop is an example, I dont know the number of cycles, I just need the last one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that everythime a new message is set, you only have to use that timeout?

```
var timeout;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (timeout)
        timeout.cancel();

    timeout = $timeout(function() {
        console.log("test");
    }, 2000);
}
```

Or, if you just need to do someting on the last one of the loop:

```
var someLength = 83;
for (var i = 0; i < someLength; i++) {
    if (i === someLength - 1) {
        $timeout(function() {
            console.log("test");
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, its the first one. Trying to implement now.